# Symfony2 - Misd phonnumberbundle: Unable to transform value for property path "phone_number": Expected a \libphonenumber\PhoneNumber

Tags: symfony

Below is my Entity,Form and DBAL config for misd-phonenumberbundle to integrate with Symfony2.8. But still I get the below error, Can someone let me know how to resolve this? I wrote few lines of code to convert the string to PhoneNumber obj then the form loads fine but my question is do we need to explicitly convert this? Is this not to be handled automatically?

**Entity entries:**

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="phone_number", nullable=true)
* @AssertPhoneNumber(defaultRegion="US", message="Please specify a valid phone number")
*/
private $phoneNumber;
```

**DBAL Mapping:**

```
doctrine:
dbal:
types:
phone_number: Misd\PhoneNumberBundle\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\PhoneNumberType
```

**Form:**

```
->add('phoneNumber', PhoneNumberType::class, array('default_region' => 'US', 'format' => PhoneNumberFormat::NATIONAL, 'required' => false))
```

**Custom Code to handle the error:**

```
if($user->getphoneNumber()!="")
{
   $util = $this->container->get('libphonenumber.phone_number_util');
   $phoneNUmber = $util->parse($user->getphoneNumber(), "US");
   $user->setphoneNumber($phoneNUmber);
}
else
{
    $phoneNUmber = new \libphonenumber\PhoneNumber;
    $user->setphoneNumber($phoneNUmber);
}

Error:
```

> Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException: Unable to transform value for property path "phone_number": Expected a \libphonenumber\PhoneNumber at webapp/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php line 1149

Comment: You probably need to use a transformer (see the official SF2 docs for explanations: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html). And this bundle probably ships with one.

Comment: By the way, looking  at the README for the bundle, the form field is a text one: https://github.com/misd-service-development/phone-number-bundle#using-libphonenumberphonenumber-objects-in-forms

Comment: Thanks @thoroc. I fixed this by using Symfony DataTransformer component.

Comment: Nice. Now you can add an answer to this question with the solution. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is my solution. I have not done any kind of doctrine mapping in app/config.yml

This solution assumes that MisdPhonenumber bundle is registered in AppKernel.php

1. **Creating the Data Transformer: src/Example/Bundle/Form/DataTransformer.php**

`Data Transformer Class`

```
<?php

namespace Example\Bundle\Form\DataTransformer;

use libphonenumber\PhoneNumber;
use libphonenumber\PhoneNumberFormat;
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;

class StringToPhoneNumberTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface 
{

    // The 'libphonenumber.phone_number_util' service 
    private $phoneNumberUtil; public function __construct($util)
    {
        $this->phoneNumberUtil = $util; 
    }

    /**
     * Transforms a string (number) to an object (PhoneNumber)
     *
     * @param  string $phoneNumberString
     * @return PhoneNumber
     */
    public function transform($phoneNumberString)
    {
        if ($phoneNumberString != "")
        {
            return $this->phoneNumberUtil->parse($phoneNumberString, "US");
        }
        return new PhoneNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Transforms a string (number) to an object (issue).
     *
     * @param  PhoneNumber $phoneNumberObject
     * @return string
     */
    public function reverseTransform($phoneNumberObject)
    {
        if ($phoneNumberObject != null)
        {
            return $this->phoneNumberUtil->format($phoneNumberObject, PhoneNumberFormat::NATIONAL);
        }
        return '';
    }
}
```

2. **Using the Data Transformer in Form**

`Data Transformer in Form`

```
<?php

namespace Example\Bundle\Form\Type\User;

use Example\Bundle\Entity\User;
use Example\Bundle\Form\DataTransformer\StringToPhoneNumberTransformer;
use Example\Bundle\Services\States;
use libphonenumber\PhoneNumberFormat;
use Misd\PhoneNumberBundle\Form\Type\PhoneNumberType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ContactInfoType extends AbstractType
{
    // The 'libphonenumber.phone_number_util' service private $phoneNumberUtil;
    public function __construct($util)
    {
        $this->phoneNumberUtil = $util;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('salutation', TextType::class, array('max_length' => 10, 'required' => false))
            ->add('firstName', TextType::class, array('max_length' => 30))
            ->add('lastName', TextType::class, array('max_length' => 30))
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, array('max_length' => 150))
            ->add('phone', PhoneNumberType::class,
                array('default_region' => 'US', 'format' => PhoneNumberFormat::NATIONAL, 'required' => false))
            ->add('stAddress1', TextType::class,
                array('label' => 'Address Line 1', 'max_length' => 60, 'required' => false))
            ->add('stAddress2', TextType::class,
                array('label' => 'Address Line 2', 'max_length' => 60, 'required' => false))
            ->add('city', TextType::class, array('max_length' => 30, 'required' => false))
            ->add('state', ChoiceType::class,
                array('choices' => States::getStates(), 'required' => false, 'choices_as_values' => true))
            ->add('zip', TextType::class, array('max_length' => 5, 'required' => false))
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class);

        $builder->get('phone')->addModelTransformer(new StringToPhoneNumberTransformer($this->phoneNumberUtil));
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'ContactInfo';
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver){
        // Explicitly bind data class of form.
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

3. **Define the form type as a service in your configuration files:**

`Form type as a service`

```
# src/Example/Bundle/Resources/config/services.yml

services:
    example.form.contactinfo:
        class: Example\Bundle\Form\Type\User\ContactInfoType
    arguments: ["@libphonenumber.phone_number_util"]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type }
```

Comment: Thank you @Dhananjay! Your code example allowed me to correct my mistakes and add PhoneNumber to my form successfully. Yet i did not add form type as a service as in `Symfony v3.4` with `Flex` they are handled automatically.